# Link (Href) to a hidden (display:none) html element

Tags: html, href, hidden

I've a problem with anchor tags :/

I've got the following code:

```
<div name="divA">
<a name="A"> A</a>
</div>

<div name="divB" style="display: none;">
<a name="B"> B</a>
</div>

<div name="divHrefB">
<a href="#B">B</a>
</div>
```

My goal is that when i click on B (divHrefB) the application go to "divB" but since this element hidden it doesn't work.

Please note, that i don't want to show divB (i want a link to the place where div are... is that possible?

At this point, i'm thinking on generate dynamically the href value (in this case, i would generate the following div)

```
<div name="divHrefB">
<a href="#A">B</a>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just don't apply display: none, just add this css for the hidden div.

```
<div name="divHrefB" style="height: 0px;width: 0px;overflow:hidden;">
<a href="#A">B</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that i need that this div don't take up space. That's why i use "display: none;(). I already have tried visibility:hidden, it works but it take up layout space... :(

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the ending closing `"` comment.

try this guy:

```
style="display: none;"
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing " in style end

```
<div name="divA">
   <a name="A"> A</a>
</div>
<div name="divB" style="display: none;">
   <a name="B"> B</a>
</div>
<div name="divHrefB">
   <a href="#B">B</a>
</div>
```